# Полиморфная связь один ко многим

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

В гайдах по RoR везде приводится такой пример полиморфной связи:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

Получается что у постов (Post) и у картинок (Picture) много комментариев. И все комментарии например к какой то картинке можно получить так

```
@post.comments
@picture.comments
```

А как организовать такую связь что одной картинке может принадлежать много 
комментариев и много постов? Что бы можно было делать такие запросы:

```
@image.posts
@image.comments
```

Comment: Описал правильно а код написал не верно. Подправил, спасибо

Comment: Ну и под текущее описание прекрасно подходят два обычных has_many в одной модели, в чём суть вопроса?

Comment: image - это на самом деле комментарии? и одному комментарию может принадлежать много изображений и постов? Или image - это изображение и ему может принадлежать много комментариев и много постов? Мы готовы помочь, но нужно убрать противоречие в последнем обзаце и примере кода. У вас картинке принадлежат картинки image.pictures.

Comment: Все картинки в моей БД можно разделить на 2 класса: первый класс картинки которые принадлежат постам, второй класс это картинки которые принадлежат комментариям. Я хочу вывести все картинки которые принадлежат комментариям.

Comment: Но в вопросе написано **вообще** не это. И в ответе, кажется, ещё что-то третье %) UPD: хотя нет, второе, тут порядок. Но всё-таки, **приведите вопрос в порядок**.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы описываете **в вопросе** вообще **не требует полиморфа**.

```
rails g model Image file_url
rails g model Post image:references body:text
rails g model Comment image:references body:text
rake db:migrate
```

---

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :images
end
```

И-и... всё. Просто в `Post` и `Comment` нужен `image_id`, и обычный `has_many` сработает.

---

А получение всех картинок, имеющихся у комментариев, будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
Image.all.merge(Comment.joins(:image))
```

Запрос будет ориентирован на комментарии, будет скорее звучать как "забери все картинки, которые встречаются в комментариях". И поскольку это будет `INNER JOIN`, картинки встречающиеся в нескольких комментариях всплывут несколько раз, поэтому надо будет добавить `.uniq`.

Comment: можно distinct добавить =)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ [`.uniq` это и сделает](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-uniq) :)

Comment: хотя х.м. не видел чтобы uniq distinct добавлял

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ он добавит **в запрос** `DISTINCT` :) Это особенность языка запросов AR. По-хорошему, `.distinct` точнее отражает реальность, просто `.uniq` более "идиоматичен" для Ruby.

Comment: я понял, я не видел такой фишки у рельс =)

Answer (score 0):

При ответе исходил из вашего вопроса и дополнительных комментариев к нему. Пусть у нас имеются следующие три таблицы

```
create_table :comments, comment: "Комметарии" do |t|
  t.string  :body, comment: "Содержмое"
  ...
end
create_table :posts, comment: "Новости" do |t|
  t.string  :title, comment: "Название"
  ...
end

create_table :pictures, comment: "Изображения" do |t|
  t.string  :path, comment: "Название файла"
  t.integer :pictureable_id, comment: "Полиморфный внешний ключ"
  t.string  :pictureable_type, comment: "Полиморфный внешний ключ"
end
```

К ним три класса, реализующих полиморфную связь изображений с постами и комментариями

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :pictureable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :pictureable
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pictureable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Тогда извлечь все изображения, который принадлежат комментариями можно следующим образом

```
Picture.where(pictureable_type: 'Comment')
```

Comment: только это обратная связь, нужно чтобы picture -> has_many :posts, :comments

Comment: Исходил из комментария: "Все картинки в моей БД можно разделить на 2 класса: первый класс картинки которые принадлежат постам, второй класс это картинки которые принадлежат комментариям. Я хочу вывести все картинки которые принадлежат комментариям."